# Using Flask to emulate PHP page

Tags: php, python, http, flask

I'm writing a Flask+SQLAlchemy app to replace a series of PHP scripts that were developed a long time ago. One of the scripts depends on a number of keys being available on the `$_GET` variable, like appName. These values are sent by an external app that I cannot control.

What is the best way to capture the key/value pairs set on $_GET from Flask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you really need to do is examine the `request` object. To extract a variable called "foo" from the request, you would run something similar to this:

```
request.args.get('foo', '');
```

This will return the value of the `foo` parameter, and if it doesn't exist it will return a default empty string (the second parameter to the `get` function).

Here is the relevant documentation:

- [The request object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#the-request-object)